# hibernate 5 call MSSQL 8 stored procedure error

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure:

```
  DECLARE @rec INT, @ret INT ;
EXECUTE @ret = udo_ui.PR_GetDocuments
   @iTotRecCount = @rec OUTPUT,
   @iFirstRecNo = 18,
   @iRetRecCount = 50,
   @department_id = 181 -- int
;
SELECT @ret,@rec;
```

I want to call it in Hibernate (ideally in spring data)

```
 StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("udo_ui.PR_GetDocuments")
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("iTotRecCount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("iFirstRecNo", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("iRetRecCount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .registerStoredProcedureParameter("department_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);

            storedProcedure
                    .setParameter("iFirstRecNo", 18)
                    .setParameter("iRetRecCount", 50)
                    .setParameter("department_id", 181);

            boolean b = storedProcedure.execute();
            System.out.println("B=" + b + " " + storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("iTotRecCount"));
```

But I can't get values of parameters and execute() method returns false. How to make it work? I need to get result set and 2 parameters in select. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution may be helpful for many people. So the issue is when hibernate sends request to mssql server, it uses parameters by positions, but not by names. So, if your procedure has 3 parameters, you should register parameters exactly in the order like those parameters goes in procedure definition. So in my case the solution is to swap register parameters to make them follow order of parameters in the procedure. So if I do

```
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("iTotRecCount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("iRetRecCount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("iFirstRecNo", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("department_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
```

Instead of

```
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("iTotRecCount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("iFirstRecNo", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("iRetRecCount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
.registerStoredProcedureParameter("department_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
```

It worked, great!